# Does Middle English "w" relate to "uȝ"?

Tags: middle-english, paleography

Does Middle English "w" relate to "uȝ"?

[image]

plow plouȝ
 
enow enouȝ
raw rouȝ
draw drouȝ
tow touȝ

Comment: I think you could really benefit from reading up on the history of the English language and how spelling and pronunciation have evolved since the Middle Ages (the Wikipedia articles are quite good, overall). Most of the questions you’ve asked about yogh would become quite easy for you to answer then. (_Plough_ and _enough_ are still spelt like that; _plow_ is American, and _enow_ is now completely archaic. I don’t think _rou3_ and _tou3_ would ever have represented _raw_, but _rough_ and _tough_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Just because a large set of facts is easily found in documentation/reference doesn't mean it's inappropriate for ELU. Asking for a definition: totally 'do your own research'. Asking for a definition in Middle English: questionable (I just found an online Middle English dictionary yesterday that the OP could have found too but... maybe it wasn't obvious to a non-native speaker. Asking for the historical development of a sound from OE to ME to ModE? Wikipedia isn't perfect or  explanatory, and explanation is what ELU should be good at.

Comment: @Mitch I quite agree – I only made the comment because this is the fifth or sixth question relating to yogh I’ve seen from this user. I haven’t seen any evidence of prior research in any of them (which is why I’ve close-voted several), but I don’t think they’re bad questions as such. I just think the asker _and_ the questions would benefit from reading up on the background material; that would make things less vague and more focussed.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Agreed

Answer (score 5):

What you have underlined in the image is just a letter "w". In old handwriting, "w" is sometimes rather elaborate, with curls or twists. See the examples at the bottom left of page 5 in this document for other similar *w*s:
[Old English Paleography](https://fh.familysearch.org/system/files/team/AIT/fsinformation/Resource_Guide/en/Old_English.pdf)", by Helen E. "Jean" Cruickshank:
[image]
or the example on this page: [16th Century Document Hand](https://web.archive.org/web/20200209090708/http://medievalwriting.50megs.com/scripts/examples/bastardsec.htm).

The curl on the right of this *w* has nothing to do with the letter ȝ (yogh). It's just a coincidence that *w* in this hand somewhat resembles *uȝ.* The word shown is definitely written *what,* not *uȝat.*

Because of sound changes, some words such as *plow* did show variation between *w* and *uȝ* (also *uh, ugh, wȝ, wh, wgh*) but that variation is seen after vowels, not at the start of words.